# Form Creating nest objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a nested object issue when creating a new item using forms. When I create a new Item within a form and view I created I get a nil on the Product object when trying to access it.
Here is my structure. I have a class called Item and a class called Product. There could be more than 1 item referring to the same Product.

```
class CreateItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.integer :product_id
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description      
      t.decimal :price
      t.string :image_file_name
      t.integer :inventory

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Item< ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :itemstatus

end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shop
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item     
end
```

Controller Code:

```
def create
        @item= Item.new(params[:item])
            if @item.save
            redirect_to @item, notice: "Item successfully created!"
            else
            render :new
            end
end
```

The problem is happening when I go to show the created item. The Product object is nil. I'm not sure what I should be doing to get the Product Object correctly created and added in this process of creating a new Item.

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: what is the value of `params[:hint] `, so I need your view code?
Be sure that `params[:hint] = {product_id: 1}`

Comment: Sorry  the word hint should be replaced item. I fixed the code above.
I think I might understand where you are going though. Do I need to create a Product object somehwere and pass that in as a param?

Answer (score 0):

`params[:item]` must be as the following:

```
#first example
params[:item] = {product_id: 1}
#second example
product = product.create(name: "", description: "", ..)
params[:item] = {product: product}
#third example
@item.product = product
#or
@item.product_id = params[:item][:product_id]
```

Try to do that:

```
@item.new(name: params[:item][:name], product_id: params[:item][:product_id], description: params[:item][:description])
```

[help link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

Comment: Can I do all of this in the Item Controller? Or do I need to create an instance of the Product within the product controller and then somehow reference it in the Item Controller?

Comment: try do this `@item.product_id = params[:hint][:product_id]` before @item.save, and tell me if there error, else accept my answer :)

Comment: sorry, `@item.product_id = params[:item][:product_id]`

Comment: I get the Forbidden attributes error. ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

I try to add the function "params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :product_id, :price, :image_file_name)". But I get errors when trying to use that.

Comment: After I created the params.require function I get the following error.
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I can't understand you, write code that is wrong, and tell me what is your rails version ??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking me to do "Write code that is wrong". I am using Rails 4.0.1

Sorry if I am not being clear. I am trying my best.

Comment: can you use binding.pry gem to make debug for your code, to print the value of params[:item]
[link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails)

Comment: OK I use Pry. I was able to see that the params[:item] is valid info, but the @item = nil after Item.new(hint_params[:hint]) is called.

My new function is:
 def new
  @item= Hint.new
 end 
Is there anything wrong with this?